# Приравнивание двух input

Tags: javascript

Поставлена задача о синхронизации двух или более input- ов, через js код, при этом, что всë происходило в реальном времени, то есть при введении значения в один инпут, в это же время изменялся и другой

Заранее спасибо за ответ*

Comment: Или использовать **[MutationObserver](https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer)**

Comment: _Заранее спасибо за ответ_, почему заранее? Есть же уже 3 ответа, нужно ещё больше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой и не очень красивый способ реализовать, то что вам нужнно:

```js
let elem1 = document.getElementById("first");
let elem2 = document.getElementById("second");
//Регистрируем обработчик изменения текста у первого input меня второму текст
elem1.addEventListener('input', function(event){elem2.value = elem1.value;})
//и наоборот 2 вешаем обработчик и меняем текст у 1
elem2.addEventListener('input', function(event){elem1.value = elem2.value;})
```

```html
<input id="first"/>
<input id="second"/>
```

Comment: Пасибо большое, ты не пожалеешь о том, что помог мне, вот увидишь)

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, то выберите его, как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var valtxt = document.getElementById("id1").value = "";

document.getElementById("id2").value = valtxt;
```